# Disk Activity for Windows 7 (and optional Windows XP)

Tags: windows-7, hard-disk

The following pictures shows live disk I/O activity from Windows 8.1

[image]

Are there such software for Windows 7 (and optionally Windows XP)?

Some requirements (best to have): portable, gratis and offline